# How to select string include whitespace exactly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here's my records (There's no single quote)

```
id name(varchar)
1 'Tom'
2 'Tom ' -> whitespace
```

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'Tom'; -> 2 row selected
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'Tom '; -> 2 row selected
```

How to select with whitespace?

like this

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'Tom'; -> id 1 selected
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'Tom '; -> id 2 selected
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM table WHERE binary(name) = 'Tom';`

Comment: do you want to find records that have white spaces?

Comment: Are you looking to select all records that begin with "Tom" and optionally contain trailing whitespace?

Comment: yes. I wanna find record include trailing whitespace.
I found solution `SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'Tom ';`
is there better way?